# dynamically add fields to nested form onchange of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

i am adding and removing fields successfully on click to add_fields and remove_fields. But now i want to add fields N times at once depending on the value of drop down in the parent form.
How to do it any idea?
here is my parent form

```
= f.select :total_section, (0..10),{}, :onchange => "generate_form(this.value)"
    .field
      = f.fields_for :score_sheet_sections do |s|
        %div.fields
          = render 'score_sheet_section_fields', :f => s
      %div.fields
        = link_to_add_fields "Add Score Sheet Sections", f, :score_sheet_sections
```

In my generate form function i only have this:

```
function generate_form(number) {
      for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
          console.log(i);
      }
  }
```

**i want to select number of sections(say N or store it in N) and then add score_sheet_sections N times**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select number of sections(say N or store it in N) and then add
>   score_sheet_sections N times)

I don't know how you're handling this currently, but if you're using a similar method to [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:osd64tVmTykJ:pikender.in/2013/04/20/child-forms-using-fields_for-through-ajax-rails-way/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) (I.E using Ajax to call a separate method)
, you may wish to include an argument in the method which allows you to return the number of rows depending on the argument, like so:

--

**Route**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
   collection do
      get :new_field
   end
end
```

--

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
respond_to :js, only: :new_field

def new_field num = 1 #-> arg defaults to 1
   num = params[:num] if params[:num]

   @model = Model.new
   @model.nested_categories.build

   render "controller/form", num: num
end

#app/views/controller/new_field.html.erb
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
    <%= render partial: "field", locals: { num: parmas[:num], f: f } %>
<% end %>

#app/views/controller/_field.html.erb
<% num.each do |i| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :association, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |a| %>
         <%= a.text_field :attribute %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

--

** JS **

```
= f.select :total_section, (0..10),{}, :onchange => "generate_form(this.value)"

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
var generate_form = function( num ){
   $.ajax({
       url: "new_fields/?num=" + num,
       type: "GET",
       success: function(data) {
           //append returned data to view
       }          
   })
}
```

- According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post), you can append data to the URL in a `GET` request

This will return a built form to your ajax request, allowing you to parse it & append to the view

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand - you mentioned you have the javascript working. I intended my code to be integrated *into* your javascript - I can post more JS code if you want?

Comment: yeah please that would be more helping

Comment: Several issues! 1. in the ajax `url`, we need to just have `url: "add_fields"` 2. in the ajax `data`, we need to have `{num: num}`

Comment: I am working on it as much as i can. so i don't want to disturb you for much time

Comment: lol I do apologize (it' morning here!) At least they're populating with the right data - let me try again

Comment: Updated again for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54415/discussion-between-g-b-and-rich-peck).

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this railscasts tutorial to add and remove the nested resources fields http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast, http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments.

If need more help please let me know.

Comment: i have followed the tutorials and succeeded. But i want to select number of sections(say N or store it in N) and then add score_sheet_sections N times.