# Passing value from view to a controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this helper code

```
@helper GetTreeView(List<MvcTreeview.Models.Category> siteMenu, int     parentID)
{
foreach (var i in siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(parentID)))
{
    <li>
        @{var submenu = siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(i.ID)).Count();}
        @if (submenu > 0)
        {
            <span class="collapse collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span style="width:15px; display:inline-block">&nbsp;</span>
        }
        <span id="Category">
            <a href="#" id="@i.ID">@i.CategoryName</a>
            <b></b>
        </span>
        @if (submenu > 0)
        {
            <ul>
                @Treeview.GetTreeView(siteMenu, i.ID)
                @* Recursive  Call for Populate Sub items here*@
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
}
```

and i want to pass the id to a Action method of a controller.
How to pass the id from view to a action method in controller.

```
$('#Category').click(function () {

    url = '@Url.Action("Index", "TestDetails");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (returnData) {

        },
        error: {
        }
    });
});
```

How can i get the id in the second snippet of code.

Using that id i have to fetch some details using a action method in my controller.

Action Method

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    TestDetail detail = new TestDetail();
    detail = db.TestDetails.Single(a => a.ID == id);


    return View(detail);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters in ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post)

Comment: no it is not i have id in my hepler which is needed to passed using ajax from the view.
i am not going to hard code anything.

Comment: in ajax call - data : { id : 3 }

Comment: @AntonPutau i told you that i have to pass aid which is different for each click i can't hard code anything.

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique! You have multiple elements with `id="category"`. Use class names and store values in `data` attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke i did that but i am asking how to pass that from helper to ajax call in view.

Comment: if you mean pass to javascript  from razor -  data : { id : "@Model.Id" }

Comment: i have to pass that from ajax call..

Comment: pass from ajax call means you need to add data parametr to ajax. If not your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply pass "this" to your onclick function

```
<span class="Category">
            <a href="#" id="@i.ID" onClick="CategoryClick(this.id)">@i.CategoryName</a>
            <b></b>
</span>
```

Javascript: **(Edited)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CategoryClick(clicked_id)
    {
        alert(clicked_id);
        url = '@Url.Action("TestDetails", "Index")'; //Url.Action(actionName, ControllerName)
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {id: clicked_id}, //json format
            success: function (returnData) {

            },
            error: {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: BY using your code i am able to get the id in clicked_id, but i am not able to hit the url.

Comment: Answer Edited have a check

Comment: hey can you please tell me that how to return a view from ajax
as in my action method i have data in model now i want to put in the view but i am not getting how to do it..

Comment: on ajax success call return a partial view having data model and update   your div tag..  success: function (data) {
                    $('#yourdiv').html(data);}

Comment: now i want to add right click functionalities here in span class=category.
how can i do that?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79008/discussion-between-abbas-galiyakot-and-shivang-rana).

Answer (score 1):

Edit your helper as following:

```
@helper GetTreeView(List<MvcTreeview.Models.Category> siteMenu, int     parentID)
{
foreach (var i in siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(parentID)))
{
    <li>
        @{var submenu = siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(i.ID)).Count();}
        @if (submenu > 0)
        {
            <span class="collapse collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span style="width:15px; display:inline-block">&nbsp;</span>
        }
        <span >
            <a class="Category" href="#" id="@i.ID">@i.CategoryName</a>
            <b></b>
        </span>
        @if (submenu > 0)
        {
            <ul>
                @Treeview.GetTreeView(siteMenu, i.ID)
                @* Recursive  Call for Populate Sub items here*@
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
}
```

and the ajax call:

```
$('.Category').click(function () {

        url = '@Url.Action("Index", "TestDetails")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{'id': " + $(this).attr("id") + "}",
            success: function (returnData) {

            },
            error: {
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you edited your action method (Index) to accept a parameter called (id)? please put the code of your action method

Comment: i have put Action method in th question.

Comment: Is there any error in the console window in the developer tools when you click the category item? also note that you have a missing ' at the end of this line: url = '@Url.Action("Index", "TestDetails")';

Comment: Did you debug if the (click) event is called using the developer tools? try to replace the ajax call in the click function with this line: alert("click!");