# Ajax won't work if using multiple params

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "ajax.php", 
        data : params+'&lakasid='+lakasid,
        dataType: "json",
```

This code works perfectly, but when I add one more parameter to  the data field, the request will not start.

Wrong code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ajax.php", 
    data : params+'&lakasid='+lakasid+'&action='+action,
    dataType: "json",
```

When I add action at the end, the code is not working.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting? Could you share the rest of that function? You are at least missing a `})`.

Comment: Can't you use an anonymous object for the data? `data: { field1: "result1", field2 : "result2"}` Also I think your data url should be `params+'?lakasid='+lakasid+'&action='+action,`

Comment: @Canvas I agree that an Object should be used for `data`, because this will ensure that escaping is done correctly. But the `?` separates the path from the params and `data` (if used for  `GET`)  is already the part the is appended by jQuery to the `url` using the `?`. So either `params` is a string containing already other parameters and `&` is correct or `params` is already wrong.

Comment: What are the values of `params`, `lakasid` and `action`?

Comment: If i console.log the code from params to action, it will look like the following: datum=2016-09-15&gaz=12&aram_nappali=13&aram_ejjeli=14&viz1=15&lakasid=19&action=save, @PhilTrep I just copied the top of the function it's much longer, but the problem I think is only with the url, because if I don't use the last parameter it is working. I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you should use an object for `data`, like so:

```
var params = {
  'lakasid': lakasid,
  'action': action
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ajax.php", 
    data : params,
    dataType: "json",
```

It would also be helpful to see the specific error you're receiving so that troubleshooting is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ultimately your question can be answered here where there are multiple solutions:

[How to pass parameters in $ajax POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post)