# How can I access an array that returned with @ResponseBody in AJAX?

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, post

My controller is returning an array. But I cannot get the values of this array when ajax is success. How can I fix it?

Controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/practice/{category}/option", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public String[] practicePageOption(@PathVariable("category") String category, @RequestParam("index") int index, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){

    String[] array = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = optionsList.get(index).get(i).get("meaning").toString();
    }

    return array;
}
```

ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                        
    $('#pass').click(function(event) {
        var inputIndex = $('#index').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/practice/${category}",
            async:false,
            data: { index: inputIndex },
            success: function(data){
                $('#label').text(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/practice/${category}/option",
                    async:false,
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: { index: inputIndex },
                    success: function (resp) {
                        $('#optionA').text(resp[0]);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Edited:** text/plain as application/json

Comment: It isn't returning JSON it is returning plain text. Also why create new strings, just assign the result of toString instead of creating a new string.

Comment: I think by setting content type as application/json will resolve the issue like produces = "appliction/json; charset=UTF-8".

Comment: I stil cannot access.

Comment: Try printing out the resp to the console in the success function of the ajax call.  See what it's being return as.

Comment: Actually there are 2 ajax calls. I updated it at source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post check this post, Stephen Ostermiller answer is 3rd answer down

Comment: I cannot access array values from Ajax success function. I can pass array to controller.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea?