# Jquery - Try to send data to Ajax but data is null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

There is function that get name from database using Jquery Ajax. This function have input parameter that I get it with below code:

```
var value = $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").val();
var typeSelect = GetLayerGeometries(value);
```

Then send value to ajax function:

**Ajax Function**:

```
function GetLayerGeometries(LayerName) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetLayerGeometries.aspx/GetLayerGeometry',
        data: '{"LayerName":"' + LayerName + '"}',
        async: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp;
            callback.call(data);
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
    return data;
}
```

**C# Function:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = Request.Form["LayerName"];
    GetLayerGeometry(Request.Form["LayerName"]);
}

public void GetLayerGeometry(string LayerName)
{
    WebReference.MyWebService map = new WebReference.MyWebService();
    string Name = map.GetLayerGeometries(LayerName);

    if (Name != null)
        Response.Write(Name);            
}
```

**My problem:** `LayerName` is null.

I use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post) and test all ways,but LayerName still is null.

Comment: Is `value` null in your javascript ?

Comment: No, Value is not null. `Request.Form["LayerName"]` is null.

Comment: You are passing the data as JSON but trying to read it as if it was form encoded - I think that's your problem.

Comment: you need to read the data as JSON and not like it was some data send by a form

Comment: How can I read data as Json?

Comment: can you provide detail code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stringify value and then send it, it will work

```
function GetLayerGeometries(LayerName) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetLayerGeometries.aspx/GetLayerGeometry',
        data: { LayerName: JSON.stringify(LayerName) }, // make this change
        async: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp;
            callback.call(data);
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetLayerGeometries(LayerName) {
    var data;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GetLayerGeometries.aspx/GetLayerGeometry',
        data: {"LayerName":LayerName},
        async: false,
        success: function (resp) {
            data = resp.d;
            callback.call(data);
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
    return data;
}

[WebMethod]
public static string GetLayerGeometry(string LayerName)
{
    return LayerName
}
```

you need to use web Method just like above method.

Comment: LayerName still is null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to parse the request body as if it was form encoded, which it is not. You've passed the data using JSON so you need to parse it appropriately.

Use the following in your C# to read the request variables from JSON using Json.NET:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string requestBody = StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    dynamic parsedBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    string test = parsedBody.LayerName;
}
```

Comment: LayerName still is null.

Comment: Do you mean `test` ends up being `null`? What does `requestBody` end up being?