# Pass differents values in ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

My goal is:

I am trying to send values into a method of my controller to update the database (which is connected remotely via API).

I have checked several tutorials ([How to pass parameters in $ajax POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post) for example) but I can not send the data in my controller I have a 500 error that is due to my ajax call.

Could you tell me what to do?

**View**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:44338/Registration/ShowRegistration",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "id": 1 }),
            contentType: 'application/JSON',
            success: function (data) { },
            error: function () { }
        })


    });
```

**Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ShowRegistration(Models.RegisterForm rF)
    {
        try
        {
            var test = rF.id;

            Ok("success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class RegisterForm
{
    public string id { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: A 500 is called "Internal Server Error" meaning that your server is throwing an exception. This could be because of invalid arguments sent to the api (have you debugged what the data is that you send?) or because some other problem in your server side code. Have you placed a breakpoint in your controller action in order to check what is going on?

Comment: Yep but actually it doesnt enter in my controller, thats why i think the problem is directly related to my ajax declaration?

Comment: i guess change   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', and can you check datetime format

Comment: I've changed the contentType and now it enter in my Method Controller! But all the values are null...

Comment: I think there is no need to use jquery.param for your data.

Comment: The data attribue is containing the values i need so maybe the problem is with the signature of my method controller? Like i cant pass all the attributes like i do?

Comment: It should.
I think the problem is that the date arguments (checkin, checkout) are not of type date but string. Parse these strings first to a date object and use toISOString method in your data object.

Comment: I just tried without the dates and my other values are still empty :/ But you were right for the dates, i need to add .toISOString() to send it as JSON

Comment: can you now post your updated ajax call??

Comment: Yep i edit it right now (i've put the whole view, maybe it will help)! I also create a specificmodel to receive the values of the ajax call, but it seems not to work..

Comment: check my answer @Korpin

Comment: Is the the whole app running on `https://localhost:44338/` Perhaps use a relative path to post to and if you have jQuery retrieving the value of a checkbox, it returns `on` and no `true` or `false`. You could use `.is(':checked')`

Comment: @Jp Hellemons Thanks, that was another problem i had :p

Comment: What the path? Or posting the booleans? Because that can cause the object mapping (modelbinding) to fail.

Comment: To get the value of boleans instead of "on". But i have to say that i dont understand why is my model has only null values (or genereric like 0, false). Maybe i have to add JSON.stringify?

Comment: Are you sure that `HttpContext.Session` is not null? And please, no empty `catch` statements. Please catch an Exception and return it or log it.

Comment: Yep, HttpContext.Session has a value of '571', the problem is my model who's coming empty (Models.InfoModel im), i dont get why its not populated with the ajax call values...

Answer (score 0):

Create Model first now(Standard Way)

**Try this and let me know.**

```
public class InfoModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    //Add your model fields here
}
```

Your Api

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ShowRegistration(InfoModel im)
        {
          //code
        }
```

Your ajax call test this and then send more data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({"id": id}),
    contentType: 'application/JSON',
    success: function (data) {  },
    error: function () {};
})
```

**Tested Example:-**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:62211/Home/ShowRegistration",
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "id": 1 }),
                contentType: 'application/JSON',
                success: function (data) { },
                error: function () { }
            })


        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Api

```
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ShowRegistration(Models.info inf)
        {
            // Access inf.id 
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still null values (or 0 for int).. i edit my post to let you see my code.
The strange thing is if i pass the id in the url it works.. like /id but the body does not work >.>

Comment: Maybe i should add JSON.stringify?

Comment: you should use JSON.parse

Comment: I've tried this: data: JSON.parse('{ "Status": status, "Cost": cost, "Terms": check1, "Info": check2 }'), but i've an error 'unexpected JSON parse token'

Comment: Sorry my bad use json stringify https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: Yup i tried with stringify but still the same.. >.> even when i only pass the id as you did in your example.. must be something else.. is it possible that the error occurs because of the model of my view which is not the same than the data model?

Comment: Still the same with your code =/ (i had to modify stringify {} by () and inside of () i had to put only 'id' or it wasnt working at all. For the rest my value is still null

Comment: now i have tested its working fine,is there anyway to check your code live??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184828/discussion-between-korpin-and-d-john-anshani).