# Ajax calling 401 unauthorized from backend in html

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem with my AJAX. Using Insomnia, I was able to get in with a successful response of 200 using the API token.

However, when I implement it in the HTML, I get a 401 response of *access denied*.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8080/api/get",
  method: "GET",
  apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey"),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
    $('#infoTable tr').empty();
    var header = $('#infoTable thead');
    var body = $('#infoTable tbody');
    var hTr;
    $('#infoTable thead').append(hTr = $('<tr>'));
    // Headers
    for (var h = 0; h < result.headers.length; h++) {
      hTr.append($('<th>', {
        text: result.headers[h]
      }))
    }
    // Body
    for (var d in result.data) {
      var data = result.data[d];
      $('#infoTable tbody').append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>', {
          text: data.RecyclableID
        }))
        .append($('<td>', {
          text: data.Name
        }))
        .append($('<td>', {
          text: data.RecyclableType
        }))
      )
    }
  }
})
```

I am not sure how to put in the token or user name or password.

How can I improve the code so I don't get the error?

Comment: Could you verify, that your apiKey is accessable and valid?

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, check the network request being made.  Does it differ in any way from what you expect?

Comment: The token could be passed as a header or as a post or get parameter. What do the docs say? Obviously if you don't add the token it will not authorize the request.

Answer (score 0):

What is this `apikey` parameter you're using?  That's not in [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey"),
```

Did you mean to pass it as a *header* instead?  For example:

```
headers: {"apikey": sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")},
```

The documentation for the service you're using should specify how to include the API key.  Presumably you have that information, because:

> Using Insomnia, I was able to get in with a successful response

So you'll need to include the value in your AJAX request wherever it belongs.  Most likely as either a header value or a query string value.  But the jQuery `.ajax()` function isn't going to know how to pass the value, you have to specify.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with passing queries which can be solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post)

As it's been said on [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70215691/10036042) , You must know where your apikey is required on the server-side, in header or queries(parameters).

If your apikey is required on queries based on the docs you can use :

```js
$.get('/api/get' , {'apikey' : 'YOUR-KEY'}).done((res) => {
     console.log(res) 
})
```

Or if your apikey is required in headers:

```js
$.ajax({

        url: '/api/get',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {'apikey' : 'YOUR-KEY'},
        success : (res) =>{
            console.log(res);
        }

})
```

**jQuery.ajax()** docs can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

And **jQuery.get()** docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).